# How can I add a mapping in AutoMapper after Initialize has been called?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a couple of ASP.Net apps that share mapping code, so I've created a generic automapper init class.

However, in one of my apps, I have some specific classes that I want added to the configuration.

I have the following code:

```
public class AutoMapperMappings
{
    public static void Init()
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            ... A whole bunch of mappings here ...
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
// Call into the global mapping class
AutoMapperMappings.Init();

// This erases everything
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<CustomerModel, CustomerInfoModel>());
```

How do I add this unique mapping without destroying what is already initialized?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A quick sample that allows you to initialize your AutoMapper 5.x several times...
Ok it's not very nice ;)

```
public static class MapperInitializer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize mapper
    /// </summary>
    public static void Init()
    {
        // Static mapper
        Mapper.Initialize(Configuration);

        // ...Or instance mapper
        var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(Configuration);
        var mapper = mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();
        // ...
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Mapper configuration
    /// </summary>
    public static MapperConfigurationExpression Configuration { get; } = new MapperConfigurationExpression();
}

// First config 
MapperInitializer.Configuration.CreateMap(...);
MapperInitializer.Init(); // or not

//...
MapperInitializer.Configuration.CreateMap(...);
MapperInitializer.Init();
```

The idea is to store the MapperConfigurationExpression instead of the MapperConfiguration instance.

Comment: Not practical solution. `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Mapper already initialized. You must call Initialize once per application domain/process.'`

Comment: It's a shame something like this is needed for something that should be so trivial.
I understand that you don't want to mess around with your mappings the entire time but when you have several plugins each with their own objects to map it leaves no other practical choice.

Answer (score 3):

This should be possible if you use the instance API that AutoMapper provides instead of the static API. [This wiki page](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Static-and-Instance-API) details the differences between the two.

Essentially instead of calling `AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg => ...)` again for your additional mapping, which overwrites the entire global mapper configuration with that single mapping, you'll need to create another mapper object with the instance API using:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    cfg.CreateMap<CustomerModel, CustomerInfoModel>()
);
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
```

Of course in order to use this new mapper you will have to do something like `var mappedModel = mapper.Map<CustomerInfoModel>(new CustomerModel());` specifically when mapping objects using your additional mapping configuration. Whether that's practical in your case, I don't know, but I believe this is the only way to do what you require.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, but rather than initialize the Mappings from your Init method, you could get it to return a function that can be called inside a Mapper.Initialize() call.

So, your Init method looks like this:

```
public static Action<IMapperConfigurationExpression> Init()
{
    return (cfg) => {
        ... A whole bunch of mappings here ...
    };
}
```

Then from your app where you want extra mappings:

```
var mappingsFunc = MyClass.Init();

Mapper.Initialize((cfg) => {
    mappingsFunc(cfg);
    ... Extra mappings here ...
});
```

or you could reduce it a little...

```
Mapper.Initialize((cfg) => {
    MyClass.Init()(cfg);
    ... Extra mappings here ...
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Automapper 5+

I have an initialiser class in my main assembly

```
    public static class Mapping
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        // Or marker types for assemblies:
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            cfg.AddProfiles(new[] {
                typeof(MapperFromImportedAssemblyA),
                typeof(MapperFromImportedAssemblyB),
                typeof(MapperFromImportedAssemblyC)
            })
            );
    }
}
```

Then in each assembly that requires a Mapper

```
public class MapperFromImportedAssemblyA : Profile
{
    public MapperFromImportedAssemblyA()
    {
        // Use CreateMap here (Profile methods are the same as configuration methods)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I hacked up for my requirement.

**Actual Configurator**

```
public static void Configure(params Action<MapperConfigurationExpression>[] registerCallbacks)
{
        MapperConfigurationExpression configuration = new MapperConfigurationExpression();

        foreach (Action<MapperConfigurationExpression> regCallBack in registerCallbacks)
        {
            regCallBack.Invoke(configuration);
        }

        AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(configuration);
}
```

**Mapping Group 1**

```
public class AutoMapperConfigSet1
{
    public static void RegisterTypes(MapperConfigurationExpression configuration)
    {
         configuration.CreateMap<Foo, Bar>();
    }
}
```

**Mapping Group 2**

```
public class AutoMapperConfigSet2
{
    public static void RegisterTypes(MapperConfigurationExpression configuration)
    {
         configuration.CreateMap<Foo1, Bar1>();
    }
}
```

**When initializing**

```
Configure(AutoMapperConfigSet1.RegisterTypes,AutoMapperConfigSet2.RegisterTypes);
```